# extjs 4 show mask while check/uncheck nodes

Tags: extjs, extjs4, treepanel

im trying to check/uncheck specific node and its child nodes as below
it is working. Except loading mask. i don't know  what is the problem. why not show the mask ?

```
onTreepanelCheckChange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
    tree.setLoading( 'Wait...' );
    node.cascadeBy( function( n ) {
        n.set( 'checked', checked );
        if( n.data.p_id !== 0 ) n.expand();
    } );
    tree.setLoading( false );
}
```

I've tried to use tree.suspendLayouts(); before cacadeBy function but result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your method to:

```
onTreepanelCheckChange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
    tree.mask('Wait...');
    Ext.defer(function(){
        node.cascadeBy( function( n ) {
            n.set( 'checked', checked );
            if( n.data.p_id !== 0 ) n.expand();
        } );
        tree.unmask();
    },100);
}
```

The spinner will be frozen but it will show up.

Comment: thanks for the answer 
i've tried tree.mask()/unmask() also tried tree.body.mask()/unmask() but i can not see the mask. when i click the parent node to check, the tree freezes until all child nodes are checked.

Comment: Hi Firat, I've updated my post. This should make the mask show up!

Comment: first of all its work thanks alot. but i want to ask samething more.
my treepanel has about 300 nodes. when i try to check root node it is tke too much time. how can i do performance enhancement ? is there any different way to check all nodes ?